# globalhost and localhost server simultaneously

Tags: web-services

i m running a website from a global webserver and a wants to store a data from a form to my localhost (like wamp) too........ is it possible.....

Comment: Anything is possible... with enough time, effort, and most of all, clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cookie.

Comment: how to use a cookie for stroring data on my localhost..........>???

Answer (score 0):

You will need to explain a lot more if you want anyone to be able to help you.

What is a "global webserver"? What kind of site or web application are you running on it? What does your form do? What data do you want to save? And what do you want to do with it?

To get you started, here's some advice on how to ask questions in technical forums. It's a bit long, and somewhat harsh, but still recommended reading.

http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html